# unable to publish data on MQTT with nodemcu

Tags: mqtt, publish, sensors

My project is to retrieve the sensor data and publish it on the MQTT topic. But when trying to publish to MQTT I’m hitting a data conversion issue. The problem line of code is below

Here is my code snippet

```
int respons;
int responss;
```

//  network setting.

```
const char* ssid = "xxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxx";
const char* mqtt_server = "broker.mqtt-dashboard.com";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;

void setup() {

 Serial.begin(19200);
 setup_wifi();
 client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
 client.setCallback(callback);
 }

void setup_wifi() {

 delay(10);
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Connecting to ");
 Serial.println(ssid);

 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
 delay(500);
 Serial.print(".");
 Serial.begin(19200);

 }

 Serial.println("");
 Serial.println("WiFi connected");
 Serial.println("IP address: ");
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }

 void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
 Serial.print("Message arrived [");
 Serial.print(topic);
 Serial.print("] ");
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
 }

 }

void reconnect() {
```

// Loop until we're reconnected

```
Serial.println();
while (!client.connected()) {
Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
// Attempt to connect
if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
  Serial.println("connected");
  // Once connected, publish an announcement...
  char dataArray[10]; //an array to put data in
  sprintf(dataArray, "%d", responss); //turn the data into a C string
  client.publish("Topic", dataArray); //publish the data
  //delay(3000);
  // ... and resubscribe
  //client.subscribe("inTopic");
  } else {
  Serial.print("failed, rc=");
  Serial.print(client.state());
  Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
  // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
  delay(5000);
   }
   }
   }

  void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
  reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
  lastMsg = now;
  ++value;
  Serial.print("Publish message: ");
  Serial.println(respons);
//client.publish("Topic", "sensor");
  }
  Serial.begin(19200);
  byte poll[] = {0xAF, 0xFC, 0xFE, 0x40};
  Serial.write(poll, sizeof(poll));
  delay(3000);
  int x = 6;

  while (x > 0)
  {
  responss = Serial.read();
//Serial.print("output =");
  Serial.println(responss, HEX);
  delay(500);
  x--;
  }
  Serial.end();

  }
```

“This is code where I want to publish the sensor data but when I put variable other than const char it gives error”
Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the actual code and use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read and impossible for people who use screen readers

Comment: Also without knowing where and how `response` is declared we can't answer this.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post. Please help me

Comment: Please include the text of the error was will then we have the context, because that code doesn't match the original.